# I'm getting error in index.js files using node,express ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Im getting this error.What is the problem i don't understand

Here is the image [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59LnI.jpg)

Comment: Your text editor is adding `<code>` elements to you JavaScript. Either properly configure your editor, or use a better one.

Comment: I have tried in another editor getting same error

Comment: this is the code wt i have written                                               exports.index = function(req, res){
  <code>res.render(</code><code>'index'</code><code>, {title:</code><code>'Welcome to my App'</code><code>, message:</code><code>''</code><code>});</code>
};                                                                                                           can u suggest another way to write. And i'm new to node and ejs

Comment: Remove all `<code>` and `</code>` elements. These look like HTML and do not belong in your JavaScript code.

Comment: yup its working thank q